# Can't get geopoint when using class MyLocationOverlay

Tags: android, google-maps, mylocationoverlay

I can't marker current location... Apps always get messeger "Cannot determine location".
I run app on Samsung galaxy mini and i was turn on GPS :(

Class FixedMyLocationOverlay

> public class FixedMyLocationOverlay extends MyLocationOverlay {
>         private boolean bugged = false;
>         private Drawable drawable;
>         private Paint accuracyPaint;
>         private Point center;
>         private Point left;
>         private int width;
>         private int height;
>
> ```
>   public FixedMyLocationOverlay(Context context, MapView mapView) {
>       super(context, mapView);
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   protected void drawMyLocation(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,
>           Location lastFix, GeoPoint myLocation, long when) {
>       if(!bugged) {
>           try {
>               super.drawMyLocation(canvas, mapView, lastFix, myLocation, when);
>           } catch (Exception e) {
>               // we found a buggy phone, draw the location icons ourselves
>               bugged = true;
>           }
>       }
>
>       if(bugged) {
>           if(drawable == null) {
>
>               accuracyPaint = new Paint();
>               accuracyPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
>               accuracyPaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
>
>               drawable = mapView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.here);
>               width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
>               height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
>               center = new Point();
>               left = new Point();
>           }
>
>           Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
>           double latitude = lastFix.getLatitude();
>           double longitude = lastFix.getLongitude();
>           float accuracy = lastFix.getAccuracy();
>
>           float[] result = new float[1];
>
>           Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude, latitude, longitude + 1, result);
>           float longitudeLineDistance = result[0];
>
>           GeoPoint leftGeo = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1e6), (int)((longitude-accuracy/longitudeLineDistance)*1e6));
>           projection.toPixels(leftGeo, left);
>           projection.toPixels(myLocation, center);
>           int radius = center.x - left.x;
>
>           accuracyPaint.setColor(0xff6666ff);
>           accuracyPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
>           canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, accuracyPaint);
>
>           accuracyPaint.setColor(0x186666ff);
>           accuracyPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
>           canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, accuracyPaint);
>
>           drawable.setBounds(center.x - width/2, center.y - height/2, center.x + width/2, center.y + height/2);
>           drawable.draw(canvas);
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

Code Activity

> public class atm_atmogan extends MapActivity {
>
> ```
>   private MapView mapView;
>   private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
>
>     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.atm_atmogan); 
>
>
>       mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
>       mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
>       myLocationOverlay = new FixedMyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
>
>       mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
>       mapView.postInvalidate();
>       zoomToMyLocation();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>   protected void onResume() {
>       super.onResume();
>       myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   protected void onPause() {
>       super.onPause();
>       myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
>   }
>
>
>   private void zoomToMyLocation() {
>       GeoPoint myLocationGeoPoint = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
>       if(myLocationGeoPoint != null) {
>           mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationGeoPoint);
>           mapView.getController().setZoom(18);
>       }
>       else {
>           Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot determine location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>       }
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
>       return false;
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get your actual location using the location Manager class/interface.

This tutorial will cover everything you need to know about that http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

hope this helps